# Adding delay and queue to adding a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, delay

I have this jQuery code:

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("nav .wsdownmenu-list >li").hover(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).find("div").length) {
        jQuery("#menu-overlay").addClass("menu-activated");
      }
    }, function() {
      jQuery("#menu-overlay").removeClass("menu-activated");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to apply a delay as in post 251011 call-delay-between-addclass but I am failing so far.

I have tried this, but to no avail.

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("nav .wsdownmenu-list >li").hover(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).find("div").length) {
        jQuery("#menu-overlay").addClass("menu-activated").delay(1000).queue(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

The solutions seem to have the `$` prefix, does this need changing to jQuery?

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much

Comment: PS, instead of `(function($) { jQuery(document).ready(function() { /*huh?*/ }); })(jQuery); ` just use `jQuery( $ => {  /*DOM ready and $ alias in scope. Code here*/  });` In your code you can then freely replace all the *`jQuery`* with its alias `$`.

Comment: Where are you closing the `if` statement with `}` ? Please open Developer Tools and read it there are any errors.

Comment: Another error is in that jQuery's `.hover()` will handle and trigger trigger on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You're not differentiating the two in your second attempt.

Comment: Post 21528660
"an if doesn't need an else always .. so remove it."

Comment: Thank you:  Roko C. Buljan

I tried this but got errors I am afraid

    jQuery( $ => {  
    $("nav .wsdownmenu-list >li").hover(function(){
    if ($(this).find("div").length) {
    $("#menu-overlay").addClass("menu-activated").delay(1000).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
 });
    });

Comment: I seem to have solved the issue witth a bit of css in the <head>

     <style>
   div[id^="tc"], #menu-overlay {
     transition-duration: .3s;
     transition-delay: .3s;}
     </style>

Example site at: 

https://www.newebsite.co.uk/sw/index.html

Comment: Read carefully: I didn't say you were missing an `else` I said that you didn't closed the `if` statement properly with `}`

Comment: Sorry https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan - Apologies and thank you